# JQUERY.Each inside in JS module

Tags: jquery, module

How would I insert the anchor's data-val that was clicked using .each inside the scrollMove function? As it works now, it will always insert the first anchor's data-val inside the html. I'd like to accomplish this with minimal js markup in this format.

```js
(function() {       

  var scroll = {
    init: function() {
      this.cacheDom();
      this.bindEvents();
      this.scrollMove();
    },
    cacheDom: function() {
      this.$el = $('header');
      this.$link = this.$el.find('li a');
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
      this.$link.on('click', this.scrollMove.bind(this));
    },
    scrollMove: function() {
      
      // insert data val of what was clicked
      $('html').append(this.$link.data('val'));
      
    }
  };

  scroll.init();

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav class="overlay-menu">
    <ul>
      <li id="home-link"><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-val="2200">Home</a></li>
      <li id="service-link"><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-val="4900">Service</a></li>
      <li id="about-link"><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-val="6400">About</a></li>
      <li id="contact-link"><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-val="8500">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<!-- test -->
<div id="html">Data-Val:</div>
```

Comment: The issue here is the event handler you assigned in the `bind` method. You have bound it to `this`. But what you need is the actual `a` on which click event fired, not the `$link` array.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, the `bindEvents` method is binding the function in the current object to the click event. But you need the element on which the event occurred in the click function. Here is what you can do:

```
$(function(){
 var scroll = {
    init: function() {
      this.cacheDom();
      this.bindEvents();
      this.scrollMove(this.$link.eq(0));

    },
    cacheDom: function() {
      this.$el = $('header');
      this.$link = this.$el.find('li a');
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
      that = this;
      this.$link.on('click', function(){
        that.scrollMove($(this));
      });
    },
    scrollMove: function(elemObj) {
      // insert data val of what was clicked
      $('#html').append(elemObj.data('val'));
    }
  };

  scroll.init();

});
```

Basically, `bindEvents` stores the value of `this` to call the event handler. Also, it passes the element on which event occurred into the click handler.

Apparently, it is a workaround. Can't think of a cleaner solution now.